# How to prepare table of content in the given format?

Tags: table-of-contents, formatting

I am new in latex I need your help to prepare table of content which is in the given format
[image]

Please help me how to prepare in the particular format

Here my solution is there whatever I tried

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{cite}
%\usepackage[square,comma,numbers,sort&compress]{natbib}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage[cmex10]{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{algorithm}

\usepackage{algorithmic}

\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{array}

%\usepackage{natbib}
% \usepackage{geometry}
%  \geometry{
%  a4paper,
%  total={210mm,297mm},
%  left=1 in,
%  right=1.5 in,
%  top=1 in,
%  bottom=1 in,
%  }
\setlength{\textwidth}{6.0in}
\setlength{\textheight}{9.3in}
\setlength{\topmargin}{0pt}
\setlength{\headsep}{0pt}
\setlength{\headheight}{0pt}
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{0pt}
%\def\baselinestretch{1.5}  
\begin{document}
\title{My Thesis title}
\author{Kamlesh}
\maketitle
\thispagestyle{empty}
 \input{Cover}
 \newpage
 \pagenumbering{roman}
 \input{Dedication}
 \newpage
\input{Certificate} 
\newpage
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{ABSTRACT}
\input{abstract}
\newpage
 \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{ACKNOWLEDGEMENTS}
 \input{Acknowledgements}
 \newpage
 \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{TABLE OF CONTENTS}
\tableofcontents
\newpage
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{LIST OF FIGURES}
\listoffigures
\newpage
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{ACKNOWLEDGEMENTS}
\listoftables
\newpage
\pagenumbering{arabic}
%\setcounter{page}{1}
\include{Introduction}
\include{Existing_Work}
\include{Motivation}
\include{Work1}
\include{Work2}
\include{Conclussion_Fut}
\include{Future}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Reference}
\include{refernce}


\end{document}
```

This solution is not shows the above table of contents style

Comment: Have you tried tried anythin like `\tableofcontents`? if it's the case you should show us what you already done

Comment: This looks like a table of contents done by MS Word. It's going to be a tough job to make LaTeX generate a table of contents that looks as bad as this one.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Yes, I have tried table of content but I do not want page number in front of CHAPTER heading. Whatever I tried I shows page number in front of chapter heading

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will give you just a starting point.

I used package `mwe` for example images and package `blindtext` to insert a dummy text document.

I used KOMA-Script for this example (documentclass `scrartcl`).

In line 19 you find `\tableofcontents` to insert the table of contents at this point in the document.
In line 20 you find `\listoffigures` to insert the table of figures of the document here.

The complete MWE (please write an own MWE in your next questions!):

```
\documentclass[%
  toc=flat,    % No intention in toc
  toc=listof,  % figures and tables in toc
  headsepline, % line between head and text
]{scrartcl} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\lohead{John Doe}
\rohead{Example for tex-stackexchange.com}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}

\usepackage[math]{blindtext}% dummy text with formulas


\begin{document}

\tableofcontents%            Table of content
\listoffigures%              List of figures

\Blinddocument%              includes dummy document
\begin{figure}%
\includegraphics[width=\columnwidth]{example-image-a}%
\caption{Test image from package mwe}% install package mwe!
\label{fig:ex-a}%
\end{figure}
\blindtext
\begin{figure}%
\includegraphics[width=\columnwidth]{example-image-b}%
\caption{Test image from package mwe}%
\label{fig:ex-b}%
\end{figure}
\blindtext

\end{document}
```

**Edit:**

Your give code was not compilable because we do not have the files you used with command `\input`.  So I used package `blindtext` to create a dummy document and commented your `\input`s.

Here the changed code of your MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\setlength{\textwidth}{6.0in}
\setlength{\textheight}{9.3in}
\setlength{\topmargin}{0pt}
\setlength{\headsep}{0pt}
\setlength{\headheight}{0pt}
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{0pt}
%\def\baselinestretch{1.5}  


\begin{document}

\title{My Thesis title}
\author{Kamlesh}

\maketitle

\thispagestyle{empty}
Cover %\input{Cover}

\newpage
 \pagenumbering{roman}
Dedication %\input{Dedication}

\newpage
Certificate %\input{Certificate} 

\newpage
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{ABSTRACT}
abstract %\input{abstract}

\newpage
 \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{ACKNOWLEDGEMENTS}
Acknowledgements% \input{Acknowledgements}

\newpage
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{TABLE OF CONTENTS}
\tableofcontents

\newpage
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{LIST OF FIGURES}
\listoffigures
\newpage
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{ACKNOWLEDGEMENTS}
\listoftables
\newpage
\pagenumbering{arabic}

\Blinddocument

\end{document}
```

and the resulting table of contents:

[image]

Comment: Sir, Thanks for the solution But I want to know that Is it anyway to add the title and page no. at the top as given in the sample.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean something like this?

[image: ToC]

```
\documentclass{book}
\makeatletter
\def\@chapter[#1]#2{% from report.cls
  \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
    \refstepcounter{chapter}%
    \typeout{\@chapapp\space\thechapter.}%
    \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\contentsline{chapter}{\thechapter\quad#1}{}}%
  \else
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{#1}%
  \fi
  \chaptermark{#1}%
  \addtocontents{lof}{\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}%
  \addtocontents{lot}{\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}%
  \if@twocolumn
    \@topnewpage[\@makechapterhead{#2}]%
  \else
    \@makechapterhead{#2}%
    \@afterheading
  \fi}
\makeatother
\renewcommand\contentsname{Table of Contents}
\begin{document}
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\contentsline{chapter}{Title}{Page}}
\frontmatter
\chapter*{Abstract}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Abstract}
\tableofcontents
\mainmatter
\chapter{a chapter}
\section{a section}
\subsection{a subsection}
\section{another section}
\chapter{another chapter}
\section{yet another section}
\end{document}
```

Comment: How to add the abstract, acknowledgement and other content with Roman numbers, and also check the exact format for that title and page no is missing in your solution.

Comment: @KamleshKumarHingwe It is just an explanation of how not to have the page number. Since your code is unusable, I created an example with the minimum content necessary to demonstrate how to achieve that. You can combine this with your existing code or with code from another answer to complete the formatting. The stuff with the Roman numerals you already have. I have no idea what you mean by 'check the exact format for that title and page no'. What does 'that title' refer to? Which 'exact format'? Which 'page no'? Note that we are all guessing here because your question is very unclear.

Comment: @KamleshKumarHingwe Anyway, since I evidently guessed wrongly, I'll try to remember to delete this shortly. You probably want to use `book` rather than `report` so that you can use `\frontmatter` etc.

Comment: Thanks for your solution I can add the abstract, acknowledgement, etc.. but I am not able to make title on the top that's a problem left with this solution.. by the way its working fine

Comment: @KamleshKumarHingwe I am not sure whether you mean you need to redefine `\contentsname` or whether you mean you need column headings. Either way, please see edited answer. Note that I've switched to `book` so that the page numbering can be switched using the standard code.